# Is there a way to create 360 banners/images (not polar) without a 360 camera

Tags: images

I am looking to create a 360 degree banner for my website where users can use the controls to pan around. I don't want a video like YouTube. I want an Image. Can it be done? How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a 360° camera to make panorama images. 360 degree images are a special kind of seamlessly tiling background, which are only horizontally seamless.

Here's what you need:

### A camera, and a tripod, preferably

You need to take a lot of pictures, changing rotation slightly each time, basically the manual process of the automatic "Panorama" on most smartphones. It's recommended to do a full 360 degrees, then tilt the camera up to half of its field of view, do another 360 degree set of photos, and so on until the camera points straight up: repeat that until the camera points straight down.

### Hugin

Hugin is a free (as in freedom) panorama stitcher for Windows, OS X and Linux. [This tutorial describes how you can stitch your photos together with it into an equirectangular projection, seemingly the most common](http://www.andrewhazelden.com/blog/2011/09/creating-panoramas-with-hugin/). Hugin can do many other projections which depending on your use case may produce better results, but you have to make sure they're compatible with the web panorama viewer you want to use.

### photo-sphere-viewer.js

Once you have your final image, [which should look like this](http://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/assets/Bryce-Canyon-National-Park-Mark-Doliner.jpg), it's just a matter of using [Photo Sphere Viewer](http://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/). :)

Comment: A tripod with panoramic head is a must or the pictures will not stitch properly, you will find many unacceptable broken lines and edges, unless you want to stitch a deep landscape (you will still face the problem with the downward pictures if you have tiles and lines, that you can solve easily if you put yourself on a large area with grass or sand possibly).